# How to print a specific value in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I tried many ways to print out a specific value  for example using array_column ,  but nothing worked.

my array

```
$items = [array('content' => 'test1','price' => 500,'itemno' => '1'),array('content' => 'test2','price' => 300,'itemno' => '2'),array('content' => 'test3','price' => 100,'itemno' => '3')];
```

or

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [content] => test1
            [price] => 500
            [itemno] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [content] => test2
            [price] => 300
            [itemno] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [content] => test3
            [price] => 100
            [itemno] => 3
        )
```

php code

```
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        foreach ($item as    $item1) {
           echo    $item1['content']  ;
        }}
```

I'm getting these errors each time I try to print a value using its key

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'content' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\classes\index.php on line 28 n Warning: Illegal
>   string offset 'content' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\classes\index.php on
>   line 28 1 Warning: Illegal string offset 'content' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\classes\index.php on line 28 d Warning: Illegal
>   string offset 'content' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\classes\index.php on
>   line 28 2 Warning: Illegal string offset 'content' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\classes\index.php on line 28 G Warning: Illegal
>   string offset 'content' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\classes\index.php on
>   line 28 3

Comment: you simply don't need the second loop: `foreach ($items as $item) { echo $item['content']; }`

Comment: it worked.  I feel stupid. anyway   how did it work using one loop while there are two arrays ?

Comment: `$item` is the next array having `content` key. `$item['content']` fetches the next array's value under `content` key.

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach($items as $key => $item) {
    echo $items[$key]['content'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but  how did it work using one loop while there are two arrays

Comment: This is one multidimensional array, do you have any other examples ?